# How to read inputs from java Widgets radioButton,editText when a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext, android-widget

This is my code so far written taking suggestions kindly help me with this project.

I have a radio button input, two TextField Inputs and a seek bar i/p.

Can some one help me read the user i/p's to float variables (G,PWT,CBPH,NHWPD)

here G is gender from a radioButton of a radioGroup, the present weight (PWT) from editText1, Calories burnt per hour (CBPH) from editText2,and number of Hours worked per day (NHPD) from seekBar2.

all the above are inputs in an android app

As you can see I have a button caliculate whoose id is: button1

So when I click that button I want the inputs in the text fields to load into the variables G,PWT,CBPH,NHWPD

So that I can compare using these like in C programming i did when the button `calculate` is clicked

If((G==’Male’) && (PWT>150 && PWT<=200) && (NHWPD>=1 && NHWPD <=3))

Comment: Please read *carefully*: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

`toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle()` will tell you which toggle button is selected. `textField.getText()` will get the text of the field. You should be able to use this information to create your if-test.

Comment: Can you please check this code and let me know if there are any mistakes i'm notable to read the inputs from the edit texts and seekbar textview          https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85itaiU-shzXzVlWVJZQk9pN3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @YalamanchiliPavan Stop linking to external resources. Post your code directly here. Nobody is going to download your code and debug it for you.